# SQL query to get a team's opponent's data

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Hey everyone I am using sqllite3 to and I am stuck with my a small problem a bit, I need some help.

This is my table match_summary

| matchid | inning | team | runs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1 | CSK | 160 |
| 001 | 2 | MI | 142 |
| 002 | 1 | CSK | 130 |
| 002 | 2 | RR | 128 |

I wrote a sql query to get every team's cumalative score for all matches. It look something like this

SELECT team, sum(run) as total_runs
FROM  match_summary
GROUP BY team

| team | total_runs |
| --- | --- |
| CSK | 290 |
| MI | 142 |
| RR | 128 |

Now I want another table with opponents records that looks something like this

| team | oponent_runs |
| --- | --- |
| CSK | 270 |
| MI | 160 |
| RR | 130 |

I am pretty stuck, I tried using self joins but not getting the expected result.
Is there anyway I can query this or will I have to change the table schema?

Thank You,
Amit

Comment: I don't understand the data model.  What does "inning" mean?  Why are there only two?  And what does one team mean on the row?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff An inning is a division of the game when one team is batting. In cricket there are two innings, For example in inning 1 of match 1 has, the team CSK is batting while inning 2 of match has team MI is batting. I wish there was an inning ID, my job would have been easier, but this was a raw dataset I found on Kaggle, I am trying to remodel it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a self join and aggregation:

```
SELECT m1.team, SUM(m2.runs) AS oponent_runs 
FROM match_summary m1 INNER JOIN match_summary m2
ON m2.matchid = m1.matchid AND m2.team <> m1.team
GROUP BY m1.team
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=6d837823992bd674ad62ed092131c6fb).
Results:

| team | oponent_runs |
| --- | --- |
| CSK | 270 |
| MI | 160 |
| RR | 130 |

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery:

```
select distinct m1.team, (select sum(m2.runs) from match_summary m2 where m2.team != m1.team and m2.matchid in (select m3.matchid from match_summary m3 where m3.team = m1.team)) from match_summary m1;
```